# SQL Query: Including Two Sums based on different criteria from the same table

Tags: sql

I currently have the following sql query

```
SELECT [Date], DATENAME(dw,[Date]) AS Day, SUM(Units) AS TotalUnits
FROM tblTimesheetEntries 
WHERE UserID = 'PJW' 
AND Date >= '2013-01-01' 
GROUP BY [Date] 
ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```

Which returns the Total [Units] for a given user and date.

However I would like to produce two separate Total Units based on a new criteria i.e. whether or not the [Units] where 'Chargeable or Not'.  There is a field in tblTimeSheets called Chargeable which is a boolean (true for chargeable, false for not).  How do I incorporate this to show two Sums one for each type of Units?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` with the `SUM()` to calculate the separate totals:

```
SELECT [Date], 
    DATENAME(dw,[Date]) AS Day, 
    sum(case when Chargeable = 1 then Units else 0 end) ChargeableTotal,
    sum(case when Chargeable = 0 then Units else 0 end) NotChargeableTotal,
    sum(Units) AS TotalUnits
FROM tblTimesheetEntries 
WHERE UserID = 'PJW' 
    AND Date >= '2013-01-01' 
GROUP BY [Date] 
ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```

Comment: also, you can skip the else, as it will default to null if not specified: `case when Chargeable = 1 then Units end`

Comment: True, I always include it though. :)